# Is it acceptable to use underscore as a loop variable in python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

As per the official [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html),

> In interactive mode, the last printed expression is assigned to the
>   variable _. This means that when you are using Python as a desk
>   calculator, it is somewhat easier to continue calculations, for
>   example:

```
>>> tax = 12.5 / 100
>>> price = 100.50
>>> price * tax
12.5625
>>> price + _
113.0625
>>> round(_, 2)
113.06
```

> This variable should be treated as read-only by the user. Don’t
>   explicitly assign a value to it — you would create an independent
>   local variable with the same name masking the built-in variable with
>   its magic behaviour.

There are no confusions here.

Then I saw some people using `_` as a loop variable.  For example, as per [this blog post](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python):

> _ is used as a throw-away name. This will allow the next person reading your code to know that, by convention, a certain name is
>   assigned but not intended to be used. For instance, you may not be
>   interested in the actual value of a loop counter:

```
n = 42
for _ in range(n):
    do_something()
```

Is this a good convention?  I verified in the interpreter that using `_` in loop masks the built-in variable afterwards. But is it okay to use it as a loop variable when it is used in scripts (ie. not in interactive mode)

Comment: It would be fine to do that if your purpose is to execute the block `n` times and do not need to bother or use the looping variable.

Comment: @Austin please post it as an answer

Comment: @Marat: I'm not sure if it is a good convention, but knows this is possible (so not worth an answer).

Comment: @Austin these questions look as unanswered in the feed. However trivial the answer is, it is better to explicitly mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of long-standing convention in Python, `_` is used as a name developer merely uses to fulfil syntactical requirements. Single-character variables have been often associated with throw-away names in many programming languages.

Such usage is acceptable when it is a clear signal that the return value stored in this variable is unimportant.

---

### In the interactive mode

As you have noticed, the meaning of `_` within Python's interpreter is similar to `Ans` in a typical modern calculator setup. When you use `_` as a variable name, that feature is overshadowed. Nonetheless, it is reversable and after executing your code in the interactive mode:

> ```
> n = 42
> for _ in range(n):
>     do_something()
> ```

You may discard this variable from the global name pool (as long as it is not referenced elsewhere) with `del`:

```
del _
```

The value of `_` would reflect the last return value again.

---

### Special cases

There are other recognized ways of using `_` name, present chiefly in internationalization and localization.

The name `_` is used as an alias of either of the two most commonly used functions of the `gettext` module, `gettext.gettext` and `gettext.gettext_lazy`. This usage has become popularized by the Django framework which utilizes that library in its internal `utils` package. For instance, when the string `'abc'` needs to be translated, according to this convention it would be referred to in the following way:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
# ...
_('abc')  # this string would be translated
```

Due to that reason, certain Python figures, such as Kenneth Reitz, promote the usage of `__` (double underscore) instead of `_` (single underscore) as a throw-away variable without much appeal from the rest of the community though.